# Check if connected to MySQL and Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm having a problem with a PHP-Script, where I want to check, if the MySQL-Logindata are valid. I found somewhere the `mysql_ping()` function, but it doesn't work as it should, because it returns in every case `true`, even if the inserted data are totally wrong. How do I solve it?

```
$verbindung = mysql_connect($_POST["mysql_host"], $_POST["mysql_user"],
$_POST["mysql_pwd"]);

if (!mysql_ping($verbindung)) {
    $break = true;
}
else {
    // Check here also via SQL, if database $_POST["mysql_db"] exists
}
```

Comment: You can check if `$verbindung === FALSE`, since `mysql_connect` returns false on failure.  For information like this, be sure to check the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect).  Side-note: `mysql_*` are deprecated, and you should move to the MySQLi or PDO libraries.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work, it doesn't return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out a nicer solution with the `mysqli_connect_errno()` function and a requirement of inputs from the database name and the user name.

```
$verbindung = @mysqli_connect((!empty($_POST["mysql_host"]) ? $_POST["mysql_host"] : 'localhost'),
    $_POST["mysql_user"], $_POST["mysql_pwd"], $_POST["mysql_db"]);

if (mysqli_connect_errno() || empty($_POST["mysql_user"]) || empty($_POST["mysql_db"])) {
    $break = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This already is more complex than it needs to be and should do the correct thing. The reason why all usernames work quite likely is that MySQL by default has an anonymous user `''@'localhost'` which accepts any username. Probably you want to remove that user. (`DROP USER ''@'localhost'`, be sure you can login as other user before doing that, use `SHOW GRANTS` to see which user you are using)

For simplification mind that the connect cal will fail if there is something wrong, so you wont need that `ping` call. `ping` can be used if you have a longer living connection and you want to check whether the connection is still working.

A simple form for the check might look like this:

```
$verbindung = new mysqli($_POST["mysql_host"], $_POST["mysql_user"], $_POST["mysql_pwd"]);
if (!$verbindung) {
    echo "Wrong settings";
}
```

Mind that I changed to the mysqli insterface. the old `mysql` extension in PHP providing the `mysql_*` functions is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but this code is designed for an installation program, so I'm not able to drop the user '' (btw: Thanks for the general advise).

Comment: But then the supplied information is "correct". It might be incorrect for later operations, though. (the anonymous user can't access all databases and can't create tables etc.)